# Use google drive to store / retrieve files using java web app

Tags: java, web-applications, google-drive-api, restlet

We want to develop a restlet based java web app that stores and retrieves files from Google Drive. Right now, the data files are stored on the local disk and when the user clicks on a link, the file is rendered from the local disk on the server. We want to move the files to the **google drive** that will automatically take care of cloud storage and disk size restrictions. What we want is that when the end user clicks on a link, the file is downloaded and / or opened directly in it's browser transparently i.e. w/o any additional authentication step or input from user. Our app should take care of authentication in the background. Does Google Drive API support that as of today ? Any relevant documentation / article / sample app ?

Thanks,
Deep

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this if the user is logged into their Google account using the `webContentLink` of a file resource.

There is an example on the [Google Drive SDK website](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_files_in_a_browser).